# How to fix 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.'?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am sending a report via link through Gmail. When I click on that link it is expected to download the report pdf and along with this, it throws me an error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

I can download the pdf from all the browsers except chrome.
Anyone have an idea what is going on? And how can I download the report from chrome browser also?

Comment: This error comes from an extension so disable all of them, reload the page, and retry. Then enable them one by one and see which one breaks the site (you'll need to reload the page each time). Then notify the author.

Comment: I have tried this earlier but it didn't work. I think the issue is something else.

Comment: Assuming you reloaded the tab each time, it might be a bug in Chrome because its built-in PDF viewer uses a hidden internal extension. Maybe your browser is custom-built and it doesn't have this built-in extension, which you can verify on `chrome://system` page - expand "extensions" and find "mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai" in the list.